# STAssertEquals reports equal strings as being different

Tags: unit-testing, sentestingkit

I was trying to write a unit test for a library. A method from library returns string and I wanted to make sure it returns right string. But somewhat `STAssertEquals` macro in SenTestKit saw it as different value even though it was same.[image]

You can see that description part clearly showed that two string values are same, yet this macro complained their values are different. When I return static string from method ( just like return `@"op_user"`) it passed the test case. Anyone have an idea what cause to fail this test with same string value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want to use [STAssertEqualObjects()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/AB-Unit-Test_Result_Macro_Reference/result_macro_reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH9-SW5) instead of [STAssertEquals()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/AB-Unit-Test_Result_Macro_Reference/result_macro_reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH9-SW6). The former is for Objective-C instances, the latter for primitive types.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/AB-Unit-Test_Result_Macro_Reference/result_macro_reference.html):

> STAssertEqualObjects
>
> Fails the test case when two objects are different.
>
> STAssertEquals
>
> Fails the test case when two values are different.

If you compare Objective-C objects with STAssertEquals(), you're just comparing their pointer values. They could point to two different string objects that contain the same string. You would want them to compare as equal, even if their pointer values are different.

To compare the actual string contents, you'd use the [isEqual:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:) method, which is exactly what STAssertEqualObjects() does.

Comment: Thanks I thought opposite way that STAssertEqualObjects compares object itself not contents. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not quite an answer (since Marc already replied correctly), but as a general rule, never ever use `STAssertEquals`!

It uses a questionable approach which first checks whether the types of the arguments are equal, using `@encode` to determine the type, and then basically performs a memcmp. So, variables defined as below

```
int i = 1; 
unsigned int ui = 1;
assert(i == ui);
STAssertEquals(i, ui, @"");
```

will let `STAssertEquals` fail - even though the values are equal.

While

```
signed char sc = 1;
char c = 1;
STAssertEquals(sc, c, @"");
```

guess what?
(Hint: types are NOT equal!)

... will *succeed*, because `@encode` cannot differentiate between an `unsigned char` and an `signed char`, which however are *distinct* types!

Other issues are with padding in structs where `memcmp` may return non-zero but the struct values would actually compare equal.

So better don't use `STAssertEquals`, and as well its successor `XCTAssertEqual` which adopted the same ridiculous approach.

Comment: Good point. I also looked at macro definition and was wondering what @encode has to do with it.

Comment: The `@encode` compiler directive returns a unique string representation for a given type which can be a scalar or a struct (with the exception of a `signed char` which returns the same encoding as a `char`). More about here: [Objective-C Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html). IMO, it's not suitable to implement a generic compare algorithm. C++ templates may   an option for all scalar types (not structs and not C-strings, though).